# Normalizing date input with redux-form example

Tags: redux-form

My goal is to normalize date input by this format `DD-MM-YYYY`. 
My goal this technique: [technique](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.1/examples/normalizing/)

I am searching example how to do it in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Following exacly that example you just need to apply some `regex` on the field, like:

`export function normalizeDate(value) {
  if (!value) {
    return value
  }
  return value
    .substr(0, 9)
    .replace(/\D/g, '')
    .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, '$1/$2')
    .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, '$1/$2')
    .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, '$1/$2/$3')
    .substr(0, 9)
}`

Comment: Some explanation of the regexes involved at each step would be great.